# Retreive upper heirarchy

Tags: sql-server, mysql, query, recursive

I have Categories stored in a single table.

```
id  name    parentId    path    
A1  Cat 1   0           Cat 1
A2  Cat 2   A1          Cat 1 > Cat 2
A3  Cat 3   A2          Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3
A4  Cat 4   A3          Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4
A5  Cat 5   A4          Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4 > Cat 5
A6  Cat 6   A5          Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4 > Cat 5 > Cat 6
```

I want to fetch all the upper hierarchy till I reach parent category id.

What I have achieved so far is:

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parentId, path) AS (
    select
        id,
        name,
        parentId,
        path
    from
        categories
    where
        parentId = 'A3'
    union
    all
    select
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.parentId,
        c.path
    from
        categories c
        inner join cte on c.parentId = cte.id
)
select
    *
from
    cte;
```

Now the issue with above query is that I gives me lower hierarchy:

```
id  name    parentId    path
A4  Cat 4   A3  Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4
A5  Cat 5   A4  Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4 > Cat 5
A6  Cat 6   A5  Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4 > Cat 5 > Cat 6
```

But what I am expecting is this:

```
id  name    parentId    path
A2  Cat 2   A1          Cat 1 > Cat 2
A1  Cat 1   0           Cat 1
```

I have created a reproducible scenario:

https://dbfiddle.uk/D3czXMX4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join with the parent is the wrong way around.

I also have changed the WHERE in the first part, as you requested all where the Parent = A3. If that was needed, you need to change it back ;-)

```
with cte (id, name, parentId, path, level) AS (
select
    id,
    name,
    parentId,
    path,
    1 as level
from
    categories
where
    id = 'A3'
union
all
select
    c.id,
    c.name,
    c.parentId,
    c.path,
    cte.level + 1
from
    categories c
    inner join cte on c.Id = cte.Parentid
)
select
    id, name, parentId, path, level
from
    cte
order by level DESC
```

Without order by:

[image: Without order by]

With order by:

[image: With order by]

If you also would like to remove A3 from the resultset, you can filter this one out in your last select from the CTE:

```
select
    *
from
    cte
WHERE id <> 'A3'
order by path ASC
```

Comment: Thats nice, how to sort them properly with level root? So that it is guaranteed that the records will be in proper order

Comment: You mean the other way around now?

Comment: Then you can add: order by path ASC
I've edited the answer.

Comment: Actually I want the records to be sorting on a level custom varaible, which we could increment in query. something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/agO_kNXf

Comment: Your fiddlers are MySQL by the way, is that correct? As the tags are MSSQL ;-) For some dialect changes.

Comment: both db engines have almost same format for the query, only difference between them is the recursive key word

Comment: True, I will cast my answer to MSSQL to match the tags of the question for other people.
I've added the level. This however is DESC, as we are going up, is that ok?

Comment: level should be ASC in that case

Comment: You mean Cat 1 should have 1, Cat 2 should have 2 etc? Because we are starting in Cat 3 That starts with 1, Cat 2 is 2 and Cat 1 is 3, If you then would like to see the order from Cat 1 starting, it should be DESC. Anotherelse it should be ASC ;-) But that's up to you in the use of the script.

Comment: I mean Cat 2 should come on top